# Want to have smooth scrolling in tableview swift

Tags: uitableview, swift4

The problem is I have 6 cells in a tableview and two of the gets hidden because of height but when I scroll up the tableview automatically swipes up and I am unable to stay at cell 5 and 6

Answer (score 0):

I thing problem is in your tableview hight or Constrainsts of tableview.